# Trying to get Current Login for DB Insert Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2016

This is the `Home.aspx` code - everything is working except getting the username:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:contr1 %>" 
     InsertCommand="Insert into OBH([Tech Name], [Total Minutes], [Off Bench Time], 
[Submitted By], Comments, Date)
Select [Tech Name] = @TN, [Total Minutes] = (SELECT [Total Minutes] FROM Total_Tech_Minutes
WHERE ([Employee Name] = @TN)), [Off Bench Time] = @OBT, [Submitted By] = @SB,
Comments = @Comments, Date = (Select Convert(Date, Getdate()))" 
     ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:contr1.ProviderName %>" 
     CancelSelectOnNullParameter="False" DataSourceMode="DataReader">
   <InsertParameters>
       <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="TN" 
PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
       <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="OBT" PropertyName="Text" />
```

This is the `Home.aspx.cs` markup it is already showing the username on the home page, but I can't seem to get it into the Insert Parameter format:

```
namespace User_Login_CS
{
    public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
         protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             string SB;

             if (!this.Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
             {
                   FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
             }
             else
             {
                  SB = Page.User.Identity.Name; 
             }
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDataSource3.Insert();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the current user's name?

Comment: I am trying to get it into a insert parameter to write it to the database. It shows the username in the homepage which is fine. I just can't get it to write to a database table.

Comment: Okay I see, do you have the markup for `Button1`? Did you define `onclick` for it? You should provide some more details, for example are you getting an error message?

Comment: Yes. Everything but the username is working perfectly. I will be adding input validations later, but as of now the only issue is the username to the database.

Comment: You should post the code that isn't working, otherwise we may not be able to tell what is wrong with it! Are you seeing an error or the name just isn't passed silently?

Comment: I don't know how to format the parameter to insert it into the insert command as a parameter

Comment: The name is inserting as 'null'

Comment: Okay if the name is inserting as `null` and everything else is working the issue may be with something earlier on in your program - otherwise, you need to post the markup here as it is pretty hard to tell why it's not working without seeing it

Comment: On the Home.aspx.cs I can see the username if I place a breakpoint at SB = Page.User.Identity.Name;. But how can I code a parameter to get that as well?

Comment: did you try running `SqlDataSource3.InsertParameters["id"].DefaultValue = Page.User.Identity.Name; `

Comment: I haven't. I will try that as soon as I get back to my desk. I will let you know what happens.

Comment: Cool, yes post back here - but I still highly recommend updating your question so that it is easier for others to reproduce. This will make it a lot easier for everyone to help.

Comment: As others have mentioned, please update the question with the actual code that isn't working.  It is hard to resolve a problem we can't see, or 'merge' code from comments.

Comment: I have updated the question. Also where would I place: SqlDataSource3.InsertParameters["id"].DefaultValue = Page.User.Identity.Name; Also, the code is separated due to it being from 2 separate pages                                                                        Also, just an FYI. I am usual coding in Labview. This project was dropped on me 3 weeks ago, and my deadline is closing. I am COMPLETELY new to C#. lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

On the home.aspx.cs I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace User_Login_CS
{
public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
        }
        else
        {
        SqlDataSource3.InsertParameters["SB"].DefaultValue = Page.User.Identity.Name;

}

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataSource3.Insert();
    }

}
}
```

On the Home.aspx page I have the following code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:contr1 %>" 

InsertCommand="Insert into OBH([Tech Name],[Total Minutes],[Off Bench Time],
[Submitted By],Comments,Date)

Select [Tech Name]=@TN,[Total Minutes]=(SELECT [Total Minutes] FROM Total_Tech_Minutes
WHERE ([Employee Name] = @TN)),[Off Bench Time]=@OBT,[Submitted By]=@SB,
Comments=@Comments,Date=(Select Convert(Date, Getdate()))" 
ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:contr1.ProviderName %>" 
CancelSelectOnNullParameter="False" DataSourceMode="DataReader">

<InsertParameters>

        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="TN" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="OBT" PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="SB" Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox2" Name="Comments" PropertyName="Text" />
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>


</form>
```